# What to look for in central air installation?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, installation, central-air

I'm having an HVAC company install a [York central air unit](http://www.joinluxaire.com/products/residential/3124/TCJD.aspx) in my house today, and **I'm wondering what things I should be looking for in the quality of the installation**?

- Existing York central heating system throughout house, so ducting is
  already installed
- 1,300 sq. ft. home

Comment: Make sure it works. If it's too cold to properly test/charge the system, make sure the company will come back when it warms up to test/charge the system.  Even if they do test it, if it's cold outside, make sure they'll come back and check the charge during the cooling season. Charging the system when it's cold out can be a challenge, and not everybody does it right.  Make sure they guarantee their work, since you're not going to want to pay for more refrigerant later.

Comment: It should be 75 degrees when the system is finished tomorrow, so that helps.